# Url rewrite subfolder to root and forbid accessing subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have drupal installed in a subfolder **drupal**, but I want to access pages as it is in root folder: **http://www.example.com** instead of **http://www.example.com/drupal**

I'm able to have this working, but it's also working with url containing subfolder, so I have **http://www.example.com** and a clone site in **http://www.example.com/drupal**

### What is the rule to forbid access to subfolder?

I want all url starting with **http://www.example.com/drupal** being forbidden.

This is **.htaccess** in / directory:

```
Options -Indexes

Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  RewriteRule ^(.*+)$ drupal/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

And this is drupal **.htaccess** in /drupal/ directory:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

# Override PHP settings that cannot be changed at runtime. See
# sites/default/default.settings.php and drupal_initialize_variables() in
# includes/bootstrap.inc for settings that can be changed at runtime.

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc                 off
  php_flag magic_quotes_sybase              off
  php_flag register_globals                 off
  php_flag session.auto_start               off
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    # Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send cache
    # headers themselves. Otherwise all scripts would have to overwrite the
    # headers set by mod_expires if they want another caching behavior. This may
    # fail if an error occurs early in the bootstrap process, and it may cause
    # problems if a non-Drupal PHP file is installed in a subdirectory.
    ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with a period. This
  # includes directories used by version control systems such as Subversion or
  # Git to store control files. Files whose names begin with a period, as well
  # as the control files used by CVS, are protected by the FilesMatch directive
  # above.
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  RewriteBase /drupal

  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  #RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

  # Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
  # Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header append Content-Encoding gzip
      # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this adding these two lines after `RewriteEngine on` in `/drupal/.htaccess`:

```
# deny access to url starting with /drupal/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([A-Z]{3,9})\ /drupal/
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Using **R=403** avoids problems with drupal "not found" handler: `ErrorDocument 404 drupal/index.php`

Comment: Weird that `([A-Z]{3,9})` didn't work, it should match anything that's all caps between 3 to 9 letters so stuff like **POST**, **OPTIONS**, **TRACE**, etc will all match.

Comment: It works even with `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([A-Z]{3,9})\ /drupal/`. The problem is `RewriteRule ^drupal - [F,L]`. It has to be `RewriteRule .* - [F,L]`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're rewriting stuff to the `/drupal/` directory, so you don't want to completely forbid access, otherwise going to **http://www.example.com** will be denied because it gets rewritten to `/drupal`. I'm assuming you want to disable requests that are directed to the drupal directory, so you'd need to add this somewhere:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([A-Z]{3,9})\ /drupal/
RewriteRule ^drupal - [F,L]
```

Adding this to the top of the .htaccess (just under `RewriteEngine On`) in your document root *should* be sufficient. If not, try adding it to the one in your drupal directory (just under `RewriteEngine On`).

Comment: +1 for the help finding solution, especially with `THE_REQUEST`. I guess the problem with your answer is in `^([A-Z]{3,9})` and in `RewriteRule ^drupal`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this in your `.htaccess` in `/` directory:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # if access is straight to drupal (= no rewrite rule)
    # notify in query string:
    RewriteRule (drupal/(.*)) $1?straight=1 [QSA]
    RewriteRule ^(.*+)$ drupal/$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*+)$ drupal/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Add this in your **`drupal`** dir **`.htaccess`** file **just after** `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} straight=1 
# "not found" 404 :
RewriteRule .* - [R=404,L]
```

Tell me if it works :)

Comment: No! It doesn't work! I can access pages under `/drupal/` url even with `RewriteRule drupal/(.*) - [R=404,L]`. I guess something in /drupal/.htaccess is overriding this... I asked this on **webmasters** and you answered me with almost same answer.

Comment: updated with your changes, but still not working... These are mod_rewrite logs: http://pastebin.com/BJBNQvKv