# .htaccess: Internal rewrite to subfolder, deny access via subfolder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my page, I installed the silverstripe framework in a subfolder `current`. I have two `.htaccess`files to remove the "current" Directory from the URL. One at root:

root htaccess:

```
AddOutputFilterByType deflate text/html text/plain text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript application/rss+xml
# Deployment scripts
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} /deploy/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L]


### SILVERSTRIPE START ### 
# See: http://www.silverstripe.org/installing-silverstripe/show/12328#post283997
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteBase /current/
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /current/$1 
</IfModule> 
### SILVERSTRIPE END ###

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
```

and one at the `current` folder:

```
### SILVERSTRIPE START ###
<Files *.ss>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>

<Files web.config>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Files>

ErrorDocument 404 /assets/error-404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /assets/error-500.html

<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    RedirectMatch 403 /silverstripe-cache(/|$)
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase '/'

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule .* framework/main.php?url=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
### SILVERSTRIPE END ###
```

The problem with this setup is, that the site is available as **domain.com** and **domain.com/current**

How can i forbid/deny the access via the `current` Directory?

The best solution would be a external redirect to the same page but without the `current` in the URL. How can I create a redirection to the site without the current directory in the URL?

So all URL get rewriten (external) like this:

- domain.com/current --> domain.com
- domain.com/current/example --> domain.com/example
- domain.com/current/what/ever/ --> domain.com/what/ever

So far i have found this answer: [Url rewrite subfolder to root and forbid accessing subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699818/url-rewrite-subfolder-to-root-and-forbid-accessing-subfolder). The solution seems not to be working in my case. 
If I access the page with this solution, I get a 403 error and an aditional error 500 because the error document could not be found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can i forbid/deny the access via the current Directory?

Insert this rule as your very first rule in `/current/.htaccess`:

```
# if direct request is made for /current/abc then external redirect to /abc
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/current/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1  [L,R=301,NE]
```

- `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules.
- This rule will prohibit your users to send any direct request for `/current/` URI.

Comment: Yes, this works. But this is the same solution as mentioned in my question and gives me a 403 with an additional 500 error. Appache returns this: Forbidden You don't have permission to access /current/ on this server.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: ok comment out `ErrorDocument 500` line and add `ErrorDocument 403 default` line

Comment: By adding `ErrorDocument 403 default` i don't get the Error 500 anymore. Do you have also some suggestions about how to redirect instead of deny the access?

Comment: Sure it can be redirected, where do you want it to be redirected?

Comment: As described in the question: to the same URL but without the `current` in it. So domain.com/current/ would become domain.com, domain.com/current/whatever would become domain.com/whatever and so on.

Comment: Perfect. Can you add a short explanation to your answer? I think this would help if someone is looking for a solution to similar problem. For me it's unclear why to use %{THE_REQUEST} and not %{REQUEST_FILENAME} or %{REQUEST_URI}

Comment: sure it's been added.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is where you locate your .htaccess file.